# How to Create a Custom Looking Window

Tags: c#, window

I have a mouse from a company, and their software isn't an ordinary window. Here's what it looks like:

[Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vGBk.png)

So, as you can see, it's not your ordinary rectangle. And it doesn't act like one; if you want to drag the window, you have to click **on** the window, you can't click like a tiny way around it, which tells me that this isn't a rectangle that's been made to look like something else.

My question is, how can this be made with C#?

Comment: Googling "c# custom window shapes" yields some tutorials as well

Comment: In winforms you can simply adjust the `Region` property of the form to set whatever window shape you want.